# While writing to a file and then asserting a Cypress.io test, the system throws 'expected undefined to equal..'

Tags: javascript, cypress

While writing to a file and then asserting a Cypress.io test, the system throws 'expected undefined to equal..'. The 'data.json' file is written successfully into the path with name and email values. Console shows the data.json values. Why it is throwing undefined?

```
describe('Write to file and verify data', function(){
    it.only('Check whether the writing to file and verify the json data', function(){
        cy.writeFile('../path/to/data.json', { name: 'Apple', email: 'apple@example.com' })
        .then((user) => {
            expect(user.name).to.equal('Apple')
            expect(user.email).to.equal('apple@example.com')            

        })

    })


})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug or incorrect info inside the docs because if you see the source of writeFile here : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/files.coffee it is clear that the content gets stringified if it is an object and exactly that content gets returned so you need to do a JSON.parse on returned content :

```
describe('Write to file and verify data', function(){
    it.only('Check whether the writing to file and verify the json data', function(){
        cy.writeFile('../path/to/data.json', { name: 'Apple', email: 'apple@example.com' })
        .then((user) => {
            let jsonUser = JSON.parse(user)
            expect(jsonUser.name).to.equal('Apple')
            expect(jsonUser.email).to.equal('apple@example.com')            

        })
    })
})
```